# Is there an adhesive with an on-and-off switch?

Tags: bond, polymers, materials

Is there a strong adhesive (can carry about 2 kg in the air) that can be switched on or off, for example with electricity or changing the acidity of the surrounding medium, though I prefer electricity if possible. I have found a few articles on the internet but can't verify them. [This is one of them](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/408325/glue-with-an-on-and-off-switch/).

Comment: I'd suggest looking into research such as this through publications, and not articles written by tech websites. Try looking at ScienceDirect, Journal of American Chemicals Society, and Nature.